# jQuery throws an error that element.find() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a small JS to iterate through a set of matched elements and perform some task on each of them.

Here is the code:

```
var eachProduct = $(".item");

eachProduct.each(function(index, element){

                var eachProductContent = element.find(".product-meta").clone();
});
```

When I console log `element` it outputs properly and the exact objects. Why should jquery throw this error?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

because `element` is a dom element not  a jQuery object

```
var eachProductContent = $(element).find(".product-meta").clone();
```

Inside the `each()` handler you will get the dom element reference as the second parameter, not a jQuery object reference. So if you want to access any jQuery methods on the element then you need to get the elements jQuery wrapper object.

Comment: But what if I need to work this `eachProduct ` inside `each`?

Comment: @EgoPingvina You can simply use `$(this)` istead of `element`.

Answer (score 11):

You are calling `.find()` on a plain JS object, But that function belongs to Jquery object

```
 var eachProductContent = $(element).find(".product-meta").clone();
```

You can convert it to a jquery object by wrapping it inside `$()`. And in order to avoid this kind of discrepancies you can simply use `$(this)` reference instead of using other.

Answer (score 7):

Use `$(this)` for current Element

```
var eachProductContent = $(this).find(".product-meta").clone();
```

Answer (score 6):

you should change "element" to "this":

```
var eachProduct = $(".item");

eachProduct.each(function(index, element){

                var eachProductContent = $(this).find(".product-meta").clone();
});
```